# adding category and its subcategories in html select

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i am trying to add father categories then its subcategories as options in select , so i did the following

```
<select class="form-control" name="select">
    <?php foreach($father as $father) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $father->id; ?>">
        *Category: <?php echo $father->name."   :-"; ?>
    </option><?php foreach($child as $child) : ?><?php if($child->category_id==$father->id){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $child->id; ?>">
        -Sub-Category: <?php echo $child->name; ?>
    </option><?php } endforeach; ?><?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

here is my controller

```
 public function addg()
{
            $this->load->model('catagories_model');
             $data['userdata'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
               $data['father'] = $this->catagories_model->get_catagories();
         $data['child'] = $this->catagories_model->get_catagories_child();
    $this->load->view('catagories/grand/add', $data);
}
```

but it loops into the first father category and display its children and just displays the other father categories without going into the if statement what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line isn't doing anything:

```
<?php foreach($child as $child) : ?>
```

It should be:

```
<?php foreach($childs as $child) : ?>
```

Assuming `$childs` is the array where you're storing all the subcategories.

Comment: no the array name is child not childs i added my controller above

Comment: The point is, and sorry if I didn't make this clear, you're using the same variable name for the array and the value in both `foreach` statements, and that's leading to unexpected results. Try changing them to something like this: `<?php foreach($parent as $parentValue ?>` and `<?php foreach($child as $childValue ?>`

Comment: strangely it worked , after 10 hours of trying :D thank u

Comment: @AmrMagdy You're welcome. In the future, always use a different variable name for the value in the foreach, and you'll avoid this problem.